# Regex in Google App Script to enclose each word inside an Array inside quotes

Tags: regex, replace, google-apps-script

For example I want to enclose each word in the following array inside quotes.

> {seguridad=0, funcionalidad=1, instalaciones=si, observaciones=si,
>   areas=Pasillos, limpieza=no, pintura=tal vez}

Into:

> {"seguridad"="0", "funcionalidad"="1", "instalaciones"="si",
>   "observaciones"="si", "areas"="Pasillos", "limpieza"="no",
>   "pintura"="tal vez"}

This is my unsuccesful script so far.

```
function Enclose() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1iXQxyL3URe1X1FgbZ76mEFAxLnxegyDzXOMF6WQ5Yqs"));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("json");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de frecuencias");

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var prelast = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var last = prelast.filter(String).length;


  var json = sheet2.getRange("B11").getValues();

  var regExp = new RegExp("/[\w]+", "g");

  /* var match = json.replace(regExp,""); */

  var match = regExp.exec(match);

  sheet2.getRange("C11").setValue("\"" + match + "\"");

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following approach :

First you wrap all , and = by quotes "" by using the following regex:

```
/(\s*[,=]\s*)/
```

Then you replace the opening brackets separately using the following two regex:

```
/(\s*{)/gm

/(\s*})/gm
```

```js
const str = `{seguridad=0, funcionalidad=1, instalaciones=si, observaciones=si, areas=Pasillos, limpieza=no, pintura=tal vez}`;

var result = str.replace(/(\s*[,=]\s*)/gm,`"$1"`);
result=result.replace(/(\s*{)/gm,`$1"`);
result=result.replace(/(\s*})/gm,`"$1`);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works too! I would have choose your answer, but you were beat to it, I don't have enough rep to up you. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Well I answered you first :) ... anyway it's ok

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample?

### Sample script :

```
var json = "{seguridad=0, funcionalidad=1, instalaciones=si, observaciones=si, areas=Pasillos, limpieza=no, pintura=tal vez}";
var res = json.replace(/(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)=(\d+|[a-zA-Z\s]+)/g, "\"$1\"=\"$2\"");
Logger.log(res)
```

### Result :

```js
var json = "{seguridad=0, funcionalidad=1, instalaciones=si, observaciones=si, areas=Pasillos, limpieza=no, pintura=tal vez}";
var res = json.replace(/(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)=(\d+|[a-zA-Z\s]+)/g, "\"$1\"=\"$2\"");
console.log(res)
```

When this is reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function Enclose() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1iXQxyL3URe1X1FgbZ76mEFAxLnxegyDzXOMF6WQ5Yqs"));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("json");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de frecuencias");

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var prelast = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var last = prelast.filter(String).length;


  var json = sheet2.getRange("B11").getValue();

//  var regExp = new RegExp("/[\w]+", "g");

//  /* var match = json.replace(regExp,""); */

//  var match = regExp.exec(match);

  match = json.replace(/(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)=(\d+|[a-zA-Z\s]+)/g, "\"$1\"=\"$2\"");
  sheet2.getRange("C11").setValue("\"" + match + "\"");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it has done it's intended job! Thank you.

Comment: @Alejandro Jurado Welcome. Thank you, too.